# Apply actions from loop to series of elements, once per element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following situation:

A form has system-generated fields inside a  with class "formFieldLabel" (this is a form generated with a from generator). This isn't screen-reader friendly because it doesn't use label tags, and my goal is to basically theme and make more-accessible the forms generated by this system. So, my attempt with this script is to...

1) Loop through the form, copying the .formFieldLabel contents into array "labelArray"

2) After this, paste the appropriate array value inside a label tag next to the input tag

3) Finally, remove the .formFielLabel class, which isn't done yet but I can easily do this part

```
// HTML example for one part of the multiple fields
 <div class="formField">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="formFieldLabel"                          >First Name<b style="color: #FF0000; cursor: default" title="Required Field">*</b></td>
        <td class="formFieldLabel" style="padding-left: 5px">Last Name<b style="color: #FF0000; cursor: default" title="Required Field">*</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td                          ><input type="text" class="l6e formFieldText formFieldMediumLeft"  id="form_0004_fld_2_fn" name="First Name" value=""></td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px"><input type="text" class="l6e formFieldText formFieldMediumRight" id="form_0004_fld_2_ln" name="Last Name" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="formFieldLabel">Email Address<b style="color: #FF0000; cursor: default" title="Required Field">*</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="Email" class="l6e formFieldText formFieldLarge" id="form_0004_fld_2_em" name="E-mail" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's the script I have so far to do this. The problem is that it runs the entire loop for each input, so next to each input it shows FirstNameLastNameEmail and so on. I feel like I'm conceptually going in the wrong direction here.

```
// jQuery
var label = $(".formFieldLabel");
var labelArray = [];
for(var i=0;i < label.length; i++) {
  var arrValue = label[i].innerHTML;
  labelArray.push(arrValue);
  insertLabel = $("<label>").append(labelArray[i]).append("</label>");
  $(".formFieldText").before(insertLabel);
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qGgwT/

Can anyone point me in the right direction here please?

Comment: `$("<label>").append(labelArray[i]).append("</label>")` should just be `$("<label>").append(labelArray[i])`.

Comment: The major problem is that `$(".formFieldText")` targets *all* fields, not just the one related to each label. You could use `$(label[i]).html(insertLabel);` instead of the last line. Also, there is the option suggested by Arun P Johny (very elegant, but I'm not sure you'll understand the code – and I don't recommend using code you don't understand).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var label = $(".formFieldLabel");

label.contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0 ;
}).wrap('<label />')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vT8HB/)

If you want to wrap the text and the `*` with the `label` then

```
$(".formFieldLabel").wrapInner('<label />')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aF6GE/)